# Ground is rising up next to patio

Tags: soil, patio

I'm not familiar with this effect. It seems to be getting worse by the day. Is there a common cause for something like this?

[image: Pic1]

[image: Pic2]

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to work out what's going on from the photos you've posted - can you post a couple more taken from further away, showing more of the area please? Are there any large trees, a river, a well, a spring or body of water nearby, or a water supply pipe? Is the soil that's rising very wet? How widespread is this effect in terms of size of area?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This phenomenon may be explained by the presence of moles in your garden. I am no expert on the lives of moles, but I have a similar situation around my house. They seem to prefer to dig soil up around fixed structures, such as walls, for some reason. When I first moved here, I would dig the soil back with a shovel or water the raised sections every time I see new activity, and eventually they appear to have given up and diverted their tunnels elsewhere.

Comment: Why in the world would they try an entire strip of my patio? Haha but really, its been 3 days and its worse everytime i look. Are they just repeatedly trying to get up?

Comment: so there should be vole holes somewhere?

Comment: Possibly some kind of rodent is digging just beneath the patio. Holes sometimes difficult to spot. Or the effect of water. Difficult to say.

Comment: I don't know why someone felt the need to down vote but you were correct. I found lines of mounds next to the patio today. He's been a busy mole.  I'll make him my pet.